# Drag down vertical formula from merged horisontal referrence

Tags: microsoft-excel

Suppose I have a merged horizontal cell that I want to pick the value in a vertical manner by each row like:

[image]

What formula could do that?

```
Referrence Column:    B1:P1
Formula DropDown:      A2:A6
```

I'm sorry for simple question, but I tried many formula and have been doing some research, but I have no results.

Answer (score 0):

If your data is uniform, the merged cells are the same size, then use this:

```
=INDEX($1:$1,(ROW(1:1)-1)*3+2)
```

Where the `3` is the number of columns in each merged cell, and `2` is the first column number that has the start of the first merged cell.

[image]